# Finish processing request in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

When I have a simple function processing the request I can use `res.end()` and `return` to end it at any point (some error happened/incorrect data, etc.)

```
get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.param('id')) {
        res.send('Must provide ID!');
        res.end(); // <-- response is ready, send it to client
        return; // <-- request processing stops here, get() finishes 
    }
    // do other stuff
    res.send('ok'); // <-- this can never overlap with the previous res.send()
});
```

However, if there are functions embedded in other functions, `return` will only quit the last one

```
get('/', function (req, res) {
    validate(req);
    // do other stuff
    res.send('ok'); // <-- this can cause errors? res was ended already
});

function validate(req, res) {
    if (!req.param('id')) {
        res.send('Must provide ID!');
        res.end(); // <-- send response to client
        return; // <-- this one exists only from validate()
    }
}
```

I believe to send the response to client `res.end()` should be called, but how can I stop further code from processing - i.e. return from all functions?

Comment: you can not return from a called function

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to return from a called function, just use a callback as below:

```
function validate(req, res, callback) {
    if (!req.param('id')) {
        res.send('Must provide ID!');
        res.end();
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

get('/', function (req, res) {
    validate(req, function () {
        res.send('ok');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return `true` or `false` in validate function depending on if you had already sent response.

But, it's not node style. Using callbacks is preferred in node.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but may be helpful for others. You could use [res.headersSent](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.headersSent) like this

```
get('/', function (req, res) {
    validate(req);

    // will only be sent if validate hasn't already sent the error message
    if(!res.headersSent) {
        res.send('ok');
    }
});

function validate(req, res) {
    if (!req.param('id')) {
        res.send('Must provide ID!');
        res.end();
    }
}
```